# Hide an element based on the existance of other classes conditionally

Tags: css

I am getting HTML from an external source and can't change the code, so in order to get the result we need I need to conditionally hide things.

In this example, where I have a level-0 and level-1 I need to set `display:none` on the h2 (finance in this case).

```
<section class="level-0">
<h2 id="4001567002">Finance</h2>
<section class="child level-1">
    <h2 id="4008036002">Fusion</h2>
        <div class="opening" department_id="4001567002,4008036002" office_id="4000758002" data-office-4000758002="true" data-department-4001567002="true" data-department-4008036002="true">
        <a data-mapped="true" target="_top" href="google.com">Business Systems Executive</a>
        <br>
        <span class="location">Sydney</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

It could be that there is no level-1 in which case the level-0 header should be visible:

```
<section class="level-0">
<h2 id="4008036002">Fusion</h2>
    <div class="opening" department_id="4001567002,4008036002" office_id="4000758002" data-office-4000758002="true" data-department-4001567002="true" data-department-4008036002="true">
    <a data-mapped="true" target="_top" href="google.com">Business Systems Executive</a>
    <br>
    <span class="location">Sydney</span>
</div>
```

The ids are not predictable, so I cannot hide the levels based on that.

Is this possible in pure CSS or should I come up with another solution?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with pure CSS, I think you might have to do it with jquery or something like that. But I'll give it a shot. If I find the solution I will post it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to do what you want with Pure CSS, and I don't think it is possible as you cannot add conditional statements within CSS.

Please find below a solution with a little bit of jquery:

```js
var count = $(".level-0").length +1;

for (i = 1; i < count; i++) { 
  if ($(".level-1").parents('.container > .level-0:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').length == 1) {
    $( '.level-0:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass( "has-lv1" );
  } else {
    $( '.level-0:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass( "no-lv1" );
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container > h2{
  color: green;
}

.has-lv1 > h2 {
  display: none;
}

.no-lv1 > h2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h2>Example with <strong>Level 1</strong></h2>
  <section class="level-0">
    <h2 id="4001567002">Finance</h2>
    <section class="child level-1">
      <h2 id="4008036002">Fusion</h2>
      <div class="opening" department_id="4001567002,4008036002" office_id="4000758002" data-office-4000758002="true" data-department-4001567002="true" data-department-4008036002="true">
        <a data-mapped="true" target="_top" href="google.com">Business Systems Executive</a>
        <br>
        <span class="location">Sydney</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
<hr>
<h2>Example without <strong>Level 1</strong></h2>
  <section class="level-0">
    <h2 id="4001567002">Finance</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

I hope this helps